# Running Sql migrations throws syntax error

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, migration, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I have created my first migration using sequelize-cli, now when I enter `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` to run migration and create table in DB, I get error
I look into documentation could not find how and what should go into migration file.

**Error**

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER, `otp` INTEGER, `otp_expiration_date` DATETIME, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT ' at line 1
```

**My migration File**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            phone_number: {
                type: Sequelize.NUMBER
            },
            otp: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER(4)
            },
            otp_expiration_date: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        })
    },
    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
    }
};
```

**My User Model**:

```
const moment = require('moment');

'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }
    };
    User.init({
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: DataTypes.NUMBER
        },
        otp: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(4)
        },
        otp_expiration_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            set(value) {
                // convert regular Date to moment Date
                value = moment(value).add(5, 'minutes');
                this.setDataValue('otp_expiration_date', value);
            }
        },
        is_otp_expired: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get() {
                // otp_expiration_date < current date
                return this.getDataValue(otp_expiration_date).isAfter(moment()) ? true : false
            }
        }
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
    });
    return User;
};
```

I have tried

- changing datatypes
- moving getters into migration
- removing createdAt

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

Problem was with DataType of `phone_number` , there is no Sequelize.NUMBER type per [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html)

I confused Sequelize DataTypes with MySql DataTypes

```
phone_number: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMBER   <---- bug
    }
```

**Solution**

```
phone_number: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER <---- solution
    }
```